# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=-3x+2$ is continuous in standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=-3x+2$ is continuous in standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

So I want to show that the preimage of any basic set for the topology is open.

Let $B\in \beta$, then $B=(a,b)$ for some open interval in $\mathbb{R}$

So I want to show $f^{-1}[(a,b)]=(\frac{2-b}{3},\frac{2-a}{3})$

If $x\in f^{-1}[(a,b)]$, then $a<f(x)<b$

then $a<-3x+2<b\iff \frac{a-2}{-3}>x>\frac{b-2}{-3}\iff \frac{2-b}{3}<x<\frac{2-a}{3}$

thus $x\in (\frac{2-b}{3},\frac{2-a}{3})$

If $x\in (\frac{2-b}{3},\frac{2-a}{3})$

then $\frac{2-b}{3}<x<\frac{2-a}{3}$

then $f(\frac{2-b}{3})<f(x)<f(\frac{2-a}{3})$

then $-b<f(x)<-a\iff a<f(x)<b$

so $x\in f^{-1}[(a,b)]$

Is this how to prove a function is continuous? I'm not sure if I may have assumed continuity with how I manipulated the inequalities.

My exact definition is:

$f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open set in $X$ for every $B\in\beta$

Comment: Are you wanting to show $f$ is continuous or are you wanting to show it's open?

Comment: @Brian Moehring I want to prove it is continuous. I realize now I had a typo in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you proved (correctly) was that $f$ is continuous. But you were supposed to prove that $f$ is open, which is another thing. But you can use the same idea: it follows from the fact that $f(a,b)=\left(-3b+2,-3a+2\right)$. It follows from this that $f$ maps open sets into open sets.